# Adding pvalues in regression

Tags: r, statistics

```
results <- data.frame(prov = rownames(reg1$coefficients), b = reg1$coefficients, se = 0)
results$se[!is.na(reg1$coefficients)] <- reg1$se
results
```

This shows the coefficients and the se...  how can I make that this shows also the pvalues??

```
                 prov            b         se
ln_Y             ln_Y  1.028167431 0.02080551
ln_E             ln_E  1.031713536 0.01992422
ln_DIST       ln_DIST -0.667898564 0.03304988
CNTG             CNTG  0.438520721 0.08357299
LANG             LANG -0.013346340 0.08555195
CLNY             CLNY  0.445627119 0.13327170
RTA               RTA  0.003917042 0.04995412
ln_REM_EXP ln_REM_EXP  1.176112822 0.09881562
ln_REM_IMP ln_REM_IMP  1.186171498 0.08737484
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See `broom::tidy()` and use that on the output of your `lm()` call.